# python tkinter tooltip on modal window

Tags: python, tkinter, modal-dialog, tooltip

I searched for ways of implementing tooltips for an application and I found in some comment or answer in this site some while ago a link [to this page](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/idlelib/tooltip.py).
I've been using this class since then and I've been happy with the result.
But recently I noticed that the tooltips came up behind modal windows, when they refer to widgets on that modal window.

Below in the code downloaded from that GitHub link, where I just made the changes of replacing `from tkinter import *` with `import tkinter as tk`, and using the prefix `tk` throughout the code accordingly.

```
"""Tools for displaying tool-tips.
This includes:
 * an abstract base-class for different kinds of tooltips
 * a simple text-only Tooltip class
"""
import tkinter as tk


class TooltipBase:
    """abstract base class for tooltips"""

    def __init__(self, anchor_widget):
        """Create a tooltip.
        anchor_widget: the widget next to which the tooltip will be shown
        Note that a widget will only be shown when showtip() is called.
        """
        self.anchor_widget = anchor_widget
        self.tipwindow = None

    def __del__(self):
        self.hidetip()

    def showtip(self):
        """display the tooltip"""
        if self.tipwindow:
            return
        self.tipwindow = tw = tk.Toplevel(self.anchor_widget)
        # show no border on the top level window
        tw.wm_overrideredirect(1)
        try:
            # This command is only needed and available on Tk >= 8.4.0 for OSX.
            # Without it, call tips intrude on the typing process by grabbing
            # the focus.
            tw.tk.call("::tk::unsupported::MacWindowStyle", "style", tw._w,
                       "help", "noActivates")
        except tk.TclError:
            pass

        self.position_window()
        self.showcontents()
        self.tipwindow.update_idletasks()  # Needed on MacOS -- see #34275.
        self.tipwindow.lift()  # work around bug in Tk 8.5.18+ (issue #24570)

    def position_window(self):
        """(re)-set the tooltip's screen position"""
        x, y = self.get_position()
        root_x = self.anchor_widget.winfo_rootx() + x
        root_y = self.anchor_widget.winfo_rooty() + y
        self.tipwindow.wm_geometry("+%d+%d" % (root_x, root_y))

    def get_position(self):
        """choose a screen position for the tooltip"""
        # The tip window must be completely outside the anchor widget;
        # otherwise when the mouse enters the tip window we get
        # a leave event and it disappears, and then we get an enter
        # event and it reappears, and so on forever :-(
        #
        # Note: This is a simplistic implementation; sub-classes will likely
        # want to override this.
        return 20, self.anchor_widget.winfo_height() + 1

    def showcontents(self):
        """content display hook for sub-classes"""
        # See ToolTip for an example
        raise NotImplementedError

    def hidetip(self):
        """hide the tooltip"""
        # Note: This is called by __del__, so careful when overriding/extending
        tw = self.tipwindow
        self.tipwindow = None
        if tw:
            try:
                tw.destroy()
            except tk.TclError:  # pragma: no cover
                pass


class OnHoverTooltipBase(TooltipBase):
    """abstract base class for tooltips, with delayed on-hover display"""

    def __init__(self, anchor_widget, hover_delay=1000):
        """Create a tooltip with a mouse hover delay.
        anchor_widget: the widget next to which the tooltip will be shown
        hover_delay: time to delay before showing the tooltip, in milliseconds
        Note that a widget will only be shown when showtip() is called,
        e.g. after hovering over the anchor widget with the mouse for enough
        time.
        """
        super(OnHoverTooltipBase, self).__init__(anchor_widget)
        self.hover_delay = hover_delay

        self._after_id = None
        self._id1 = self.anchor_widget.bind("<Enter>", self._show_event)
        self._id2 = self.anchor_widget.bind("<Leave>", self._hide_event)
        self._id3 = self.anchor_widget.bind("<Button>", self._hide_event)

    def __del__(self):
        try:
            self.anchor_widget.unbind("<Enter>", self._id1)
            self.anchor_widget.unbind("<Leave>", self._id2)  # pragma: no cover
            self.anchor_widget.unbind("<Button>", self._id3)  # pragma: no cover
        except tk.TclError:  # pragma: no cover
            pass
        super(OnHoverTooltipBase, self).__del__()

    def _show_event(self, event=None):
        """event handler to display the tooltip"""
        if self.hover_delay:
            self.schedule()
        else:
            self.showtip()

    def _hide_event(self, event=None):
        """event handler to hide the tooltip"""
        self.hidetip()

    def schedule(self):
        """schedule the future display of the tooltip"""
        self.unschedule()
        self._after_id = self.anchor_widget.after(self.hover_delay,
                                                  self.showtip)

    def unschedule(self):
        """cancel the future display of the tooltip"""
        after_id = self._after_id
        self._after_id = None
        if after_id:
            self.anchor_widget.after_cancel(after_id)

    def hidetip(self):
        """hide the tooltip"""
        try:
            self.unschedule()
        except tk.TclError:  # pragma: no cover
            pass
        super(OnHoverTooltipBase, self).hidetip()

    def showcontents(self):
        """content display hook for sub-classes"""
        # See ToolTip for an example
        raise NotImplementedError


class Hovertip(OnHoverTooltipBase):
    """A tooltip that pops up when a mouse hovers over an anchor widget."""
    def __init__(self, anchor_widget, text, hover_delay=1000):
        """Create a text tooltip with a mouse hover delay.
        anchor_widget: the widget next to which the tooltip will be shown
        hover_delay: time to delay before showing the tooltip, in milliseconds
        Note that a widget will only be shown when showtip() is called,
        e.g. after hovering over the anchor widget with the mouse for enough
        time.
        """
        super(Hovertip, self).__init__(anchor_widget, hover_delay=hover_delay)
        self.text = text

    def showcontents(self):
        label = tk.Label(self.tipwindow, text=self.text, justify=tk.LEFT,
                         background="#ffffe0", relief=tk.SOLID, borderwidth=1)
        label.pack()
```

Now some code illustrating the problem I'm having:

```
class PopupWindow:
    def __init__(self, parent):
        self.parent = parent
        self.gui = tk.Toplevel(self.parent)
        self.gui.geometry("100x30")
        self.gui.wait_visibility()
        self.ok_button = tk.Button(self.gui, text="OK", command=self.on_ok_button)
        self.ok_button.pack()
        Hovertip(self.ok_button, text="OK button", hover_delay=500)

    def on_ok_button(self):
        self.gui.destroy()

    def show(self):
        self.gui.grab_set()
        # Hovertip(self.ok_button, text="OK button", hover_delay=500)
        self.gui.wait_window()
        return 0


class App(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs)
        self.parent = parent
        button = tk.Button(parent, text="Button -- no hover delay", command=self.button)
        button.pack()
        Hovertip(button, "This is tooltip\ntext for button.", hover_delay=0)

    def button(self):
        window = PopupWindow(self.parent)
        window.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    App(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

You'll notice that the tooltip for the OK button in the modal window appears behind the window (I'm changing the geometry of the window for otherwise it would be so small that we wouldn't actually notice this).
Of course this becomes a problem in a real window with several widgets the tips for some of them will not be seen at all.

Apparently there are two ways around the problem: one is to delete the line `self.gui.wait_visibility()` in the `__init__` of the `PopupWindow` class;
the other is to delete the `self.gui.grab_set()` in the `show()` method.
With any of these the window is no longer modal (if I get the meaning right: I mean I want the window to stay on top and prevent changes in the parent window while it exists).

The commented line in the `show` method was my tentative of working around it by defining the tooltip after the `grab_set` so that it might come on top, but it doesn't work either.

I suppose there must be an way of doing this properly using this class for tooltips.
How can I do it?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you using Windows or Linux?

Comment: @TheLizzard It's Mac. By the way, I've just tried with Pmw, and I have the same problem.

Comment: I can't find any problems when running this on Windows 10. If I understand your problem correctly you might want to call `<pop up window>.attributes("-topmost", True)` so that it always stays on the top of the other windows.

Comment: @TheLizzard But the popup window does stay on top with the code above. The problem is that the tooltips for widgets on that window which come up behind the window, while they should come on top of it

Comment: So you are saying that the `Hovertip` window is behind the main window?

Comment: @TheLizzard when applied to the button in the main window, it comes in the right place, above the window; when we click that button, a modal window appears, with another button, which has its own tip, and it's that tip that comes behind the modal window. We can still see it because the window is small, but with a proper window with working widgets, some of which far from the edge of the window, their tips won't be visible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution.
Apparently, someone had the same problem, although with a different class for tooltips.
I refer to [this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9135302/using-python-tkinter-always-on-top-window-isnt-showing-custom-class-tooltip-t/9135397).

The solution is to add the line `tw.wm_attributes("-topmost", 1)` somewhere in the `showtip` method of the `TooltipBase` class.
I did it as a last line, but I'm not sure it doesn't work some other place; I know it doesn't if immediately after `tw.wm_overrideredirect(1)`.